# Is there a way to host documents?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Is there a feature of the site that enables hosting documents in order to prevent the loss of source material to dead links?

If not, could there be?

Comment: I don't believe there is such a feature for anything but images. I added an explicit request for such a feature to your question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, thanks.

Comment: Who owns the copyright on these documents? If they're out of copyright, wouldn't Wikisource be a good bet?

Comment: @TRiG, I have no idea if the particular document I have in mind is specifically copyrighted or it falls under some assumption of copyright or what. But in general terms, you raise an interesting concern. What do we do about copyrighted material if the original site is either unstable or hostile to other sites that link to their source material(s)?

Comment: There's always `archive.org`, I suppose.

Comment: I don't think we have license to republish copyrighted material, regardless of the source's attitude or availability.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, right, unless it's copyrighted but licensed so others *can* republish it (as, e.g., posts on this site are).

Comment: @TRiG: archive.org removes books as well: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7949/is-the-tower-of-babel-discussed-in-other-jewish-texts/8546#comment39710_8546

Comment: We have the same issue already with copyrighted images and the [community](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/users/170/msh210) moderates to ensure that the image feature is only used legally. I see no reason why we couldn't have the same policy regarding documents and other files.